# Git commit creates hundreds of feature tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rspec

I do my testing with RSpec that goes in the Spec folder. However, the other day I created a new model/controller called 'Articles' and I somehow have it so now when I run my bin/rspec command it seems all my feature tests have been copied into the app/views/articles folder (they're still in the specs folder). Rather than running the 42 test I have in a few seconds it is taking about 5 minutes to run several hundred tests over a few minutes. I have deleted the offending folders from the views/artciles folder but I just wondered if anyone knew what I had done (because I certainly don't)!

The message I got when I pushed to github was:

```
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/admin/admin_adds_an_article_category_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/admin/admin_modifies_articles_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/admin/admin_modifies_steps_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/admin/admin_sessions_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/admin/admin_adds_an_article_category_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_articles_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_steps_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/admin/admin_sessions_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_adds_an_article_category_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_articles_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_steps_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_sessions_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_adds_an_article_category_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_articles_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_steps_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_sessions_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_adds_an_article_category_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_articles_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_steps_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_sessions_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_adds_an_article_category_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_articles_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_steps_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_sessions_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_adds_an_article_category_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_articles_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_steps_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_sessions_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/.keep
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_adds_an_article_category_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_articles_spec.rb
 create mode 100644 app/views/articles/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/user/features/admin/admin_modifies_steps_spec.rb
```

Comment: Why don't you add the unwanted paths to your .gitignore file to avoid pushing on server ?

Comment: It's not really a problem where they are because I can delete them. I just wondered if anyone knew why, any time I create a views folder, I get all these tests. Thanks

Comment: How did you create this model and controller, did you use `rails genrate`? Also - what gems do you have installed?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to commit those files into GitHub, you should add it to `.gitignore` file, but make sure you remove all folders, files already committed into your git repos.